# Indirect call to a not exported function

Tags: windows, debugging, dll

I was debugging a program (not Microsoft's) and noticed an indirect call to a Windows-DLL function, where the weird thing is that this Win-DLL function is not in the export list of that Win-DLL. (In my specific example I saw a jump to msftedit.dll in SysWOW64 folder).

How can the program know where to jump to in each windows version? since in different versions of Windows, this DLL is different.

Comment: Probably just a call to a function pointer.

Comment: But where the non-MS got that pointer from? As I said, it is not exported, so how could it reference to it?

Comment: One of the functions that *is* exported will have provided the application with the pointer, either directly or indirectly.